# How to load pretrained googlenet model in pytorch

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch, pre-trained-model, torchvision

I'm trying to finetune a GoogleNet network over a specific dataset but I'm having trouble loading it. What I try now is:

```
model = torchvision.models.googlenet(pretrained=True)
```

However I get an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'torchvision.models' has no attribute 'googlenet'
```

I have the latest version of torchvision but reinstalled just to be sure, the error is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use the GoogLeNet `inception_v3` model (["Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567)):

```
import torchvision
google_net = torchvision.models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
```